# Assembler : Turn 3 lines into 1

Tags: assembly, x86

Question (My problem is with B) :

Assuming DX = 0XDB00

A) What is the value of DH after these commands :

```
SHR DX, 1
OR  DH,DL
XOR DL, DL
```

B) Write 1 line to replace the above 3 lines

And this is what I got to :

[image]

At first I thought, maybe its "SHR AH, 1" but that would leave the MSB 0 and not 1.
I also tried looking at the DEC and HEX values with no luck of finding a pattern.

NOTE : I'm starting to think that maybe the question was badly written and they meant how to get to the result we got in A in the particular case where DX is 0XDB00. Althought that doesn't sound right since the answer could just be `mov DX,0xED00`

Comment: "I would share my results" we would appreciate that. We don't do your homework, but if you tell us what you've tried we might be able to tell you where and how you messed up.

Comment: No, please share your results, and ask why they are wrong.

Comment: I can answer b) with `mov DX,0nnnnh`.

Comment: Is the single line replacement supposed to contain only one instruction?  (most asm syntaxes have an instruction-separator character that lets you put multiple insns on the same line).  Is that one instruction supposed to produce the same result as those three insns for all cases, or just for the `DX=0xDB00` case?

Comment: Also, please type or copy the text as text, rather than posting a picture of it.  It's useful for people to be able to copy it into answers or whatever.  Also, some SO readers are blind.  There's absolutely no benefit to the image here, so this is pure laziness on your part to not type out a couple short lines of text.

Comment: It's easier to copy your code and paste it in my compiler, I can't do that with an image. You are  making harder for us to help you.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling you lazy, because you're the one asking other people for help.  It's your responsibility to format your question well, not to expect other people to do it for you.  Instead of every reader that wants to copy the text having to do it themselves, you could have taken 1 minute to use a code-formatting text block to achieve basically the same formatting but with plain text.

Comment: Not if you're blind, or if you want to copy-paste it into something to test a possible replacement expression.

Comment: A better way to say this: question readers are supposed to be lazy.  As the asker, it's your job to serve up the question in a format that's as easy to digest as possible, so people reading it only have to spend any effort on actually answering the question, not dealing with your mess.  Pictures of text are not welcome on StackOverflow for a variety of reasons, especially when they don't add anything that a simple code-formatting block could have done.

Comment: Another way to say this: You want help from others. Then it is up to you to make it as easy as possible for them to help you. Posting a picture means they must manually copy the code if they want to test it, and that might turn off many people. Make it easy, and more people will be inclined to help you and your chances of getting a good result are higher.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer supposed to be  `ror dh, 1`?

That gives the same result as your sequence when `dl` is already 0, but doesn't work in the general case where DX holds an arbitrary 16bit value.  If you can't assume that, I don't think the question is answerable (unless you take it literally as "one line", and just put multiple instructions on the same line, which is possible in GAS and NASM syntax at least.)

---

Here's how the original does the same thing as a rotate (assuming DL is zero):

`SHR` always leaves the high bit zero, and shifts the low bit of DH into the high bit of DL.

The `OR` sets the high bit of DH to the bit shifted out into the high bit of DL.  (And if DL was non-zero initially, those bits will affect DH)

`XOR` zeroes DL again.

Answer (score 0):

`ADD DX,1200` will get the same result into the DX register as the 3 lines above.
Used ollydbg for this, opened up one of my programs and edited it.
First I tested the code that you have given me.
`MOV DX,0xDB00
SHR DX,1
OR DH,DL
XOR DL,DL`
and after this I checked the DX register.
Once I had the value I just needed to use a hex calculator.

Comment: That only works for this one starting value.  You might as well use a `mov dh, ...`.  The constant you need to add is different for most different starting values, so it's not as good an answer as a rotate, IMO.

Comment: Hmm, can you explain why you are adding 1200? According to the second image I posted, all you had to do is add 4608 (decimal of right - decimal of left)

Comment: @OrBetzalel he probably meant 0x1200 which is 4608 decimal.